# How do I set the icon shown to the user for my Spotify connected app?

Tags: oauth, spotify

We've setup a Spotify developer app on Spotify, and while we can edit the name and description, I can't find anywhere that lets me change the icon / logo we show.  (You just get the generic "A in a box" they provide.)

Is there a way to change this? Comparing it to Facebook or other auth services that show the user that they are setting up a connection between our app, and that it's legitimate with our icon shown.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, answered my own question - it appears that Spotify doesn't show that icon to the user with their login anyway.  So that's why you can't set it.

I believe it was settable in the past, because I see that my Playstation connection has a proper icon - but they must have removed that feature.